# Auto-Hide/Auto-Show Interface

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am currently trying to figure out what the best practice would be to auto-show or auto-hide a part of an interface. Here is a screenshot of the application in both states:

[image]

Currently there's a single button that allows for toggling, but under request they wish it to be set to automatic. The underlaying map is also in developement so that it will be fully interactive aswell so it might not be as easy to implement as I'd hope it to be.

I would like to know if there is a simple method to achieve this.
If not, what are more advanced alternatives?
Is this a good idea to implement ontop of an interactive map?

Comment: What do you mean by automatic? when would it show and when would it hide?

Comment: Also from that screenshot you are obscuring almost half of that map area with that overlay. I don't read the language but what if there is something more important on the map.

Comment: @Rotem The intention is to have the entire menu and gridview to show once you hover over that area and hide it when you hover away from it.

Comment: @TheKingDave The map stretches out at a resolution up to 2500x1300 something so the interface doesn't hide all that much. But the map automatically zooms in on the displayed routes and so sometimes information gets hidden under that interface. I'm trying to dedicate as much screenspace to the map and make the interface as much minimal and hidden as possible.

Comment: Why not have these at the top of the screen like some sort of ribbon rather than as something that covers the map? You can have this "Area" to update using the mousehover/mouseleave events?

Comment: Given that they wish to see a whole lot in the gridview on the left. (About 40 objects at a glance) a vertical solution is the only option. That is why I crammed things in the top left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
namespace autohide
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int pin = 0;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            panel1.Visible = false;

        }
        void ChangeIconPin()
        {
            switch (pin)
            {
                case 0:
                    //Changes the pin-icon to display a unpinned frame.
                    this.button_Pin.BackgroundImage = autohidefixv2.Properties.Resources._55_roto;
                    break;

                case 1:
                    //Changes the pin-icon to display a pinned frame.
                    this.button_Pin.BackgroundImage = autohidefixv2.Properties.Resources._55_2;
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("sdasdad");
                    break;
            }
        }


        private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (pin == 0)
            {
                panel1.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private void button_Pin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (pin)
            {
                case 0:
                    pin = 1;
                    ChangeIconPin();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    pin = 0;
                    ChangeIconPin();
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("asdasda");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also added a pin that can pin the panel to disable autohide if desired by the user. You can find a sample project here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11441219/autohidefixv2.zip

[image]